# Foreign Prime Minister / President

Tags: president, prime-minister, citizenship

In the business it is very common to open leading positions to any candidate, even those who worked with competition before, in believe to getting the most skilled/competitive leader.

Why is it not the same in politics? Is (or has) there any country where a foreign citizen can become Prime Minister or President?

Comment: Andorra has two co-princes (which act as the heads of state), which are the bishop of Urgell and the president of France.

Comment: Being legal to became president or prime minister is not the same as being voted by electors in the country. Being citizen may not be a legal requirement but it may be highly correlated with some preferences of electors, making the event of a non citizen being elected unlikely.

Comment: Don't you think corporate executives are chosen for their skills, with little regard to politics while with politicians it's the other way round?

Comment: The highest authority in Bosnia and Herzegovina is the High Representative, who has never been a citizen of Bosnia and Herzegovina.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is it not the same in politics?

Most defense-related jobs [even relatively low-level ones] have much stricter nationality and loyalty requirements than that of a random CEO.

The president or PM is often the head of the armed forces in some way, so there's that issue if one were holding them to a much looser standard in that regard.

---

> Is (or has) there any country where a foreign citizen can become Prime Minister or President?

There are examples of PMs being dual nationals (or former dual nationals). Iraq perhaps had a record of these [recently](https://www.newarab.com/news/iraq-pm-designate-renounces-british-nationality-ahead-parliament-vote):

> Outgoing premier Adel Abdel Mahdi [PM 2018-2020] holds French citizenship and former prime minister Haider Al-Abadi [PM 2014-2018] is also a British national.

Not mentioned in that 2020 piece but the president of Iraq 2018-2022, Barham Salih, also held British citizenship, according to Wikipedia.

(FWTW, there [was](https://www.refworld.org/docid/3ae6b4ec38.html) a Baathist era law 46/1963 forbidding dual citizenship altogether [art. 11], but his was abrogated after Saddam's ousting.)

As for someone not being a citizen of the country in question at all, that's a much tougher proposition, and I'm not sure I can come with examples.

But for minister jobs below PM, perhaps this is an interesting [enough] example [from 2014](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-30348945)...

> In an unusual development, three foreigners were appointed to Ukraine's new government this week.
>
> US-born Natalie Jaresko became finance minister, Lithuania's Aivaras Abromavicius economy minister and Aleksandre Kvitashvili - from Georgia - health minister. Hours before the vote in the parliament that installed them, all three were granted Ukrainian citizenship by President Petro Poroshenko.
>
> The move is part of a fresh anti-corruption drive in Kiev. Politicians and other officials supportive of the idea say outsiders in the cabinet will have fewer vested interests, or links to local lobbyists. President Poroshenko also said Ukraine should make use of "the best international experience".

So at least the motivation in this case appears to have been along the lines you asked. (The [loyalty] issue that I mentioned earlier did come up in [pro-Russian] opposition discourse rather quickly; there are some quotes to that effect in the article that I won't add here as being rather predictable in their contents.)

I'm not sure there are any longer-term trackers on such issues, but Papua New Guinea [had](https://devpolicy.org/papua-new-guineas-foreign-ministers-20230531/) some 17 naturalized citizens become ministers. Most (13) were from Australia. There average per-cabinet was also relatively high (4) according to that blog's calculations.

Answer (score 4):

In the UK, any Commonwealth citizen is eligible to be an MP, and so eligible to be Prime Minister.

(and any descendent of Sophia of Hannover is eligible to be Monarch, there are no nationality requirements)

Your analogy is false, since a requirement for being a leader of company is that you are employed by that company.  By analogy, to be a leader of a country you are expected to be a member (ie a citizen) of the country, even he they had previously held another citizenship.

There are recent examples of UK Prime Ministers who would have had the right to claim another nationality.  Boris Johnson was born in New York, and was a US citizen until 2016 (when he renounced it).

Comment: FWTW, BJ apparently had US citizenship (too) but renounced it in 2016 https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2017/feb/08/boris-johnson-renounces-us-citizenship-record-2016-uk-foreign-secretary

Comment: Birth in the United States does not allow one to claim US citizenship; it either makes one a US citizen or not (if one's parents have diplomatic immunity).

Comment: @phoog, thank you, clarified.

Answer (score -2):

> Vaira Vīķe was born in Riga, Latvia. At the end of 1944, as the second Soviet occupation of Latvia began, her parents escaped to Nazi Germany.

> [Vaira Vīķe-Freiberga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaira_V%C4%AB%C4%B7e-Freiberga) is a Latvian politician who served as the sixth President of Latvia from 1999 to 2007

> Vaira Vīķe attended Victoria College of the University of Toronto, graduating with a Bachelor of Arts in 1958 and a Master of Arts in 1960

> In June 1998 she was elected Professor emerita at the University of Montreal and returned to her native land, Latvia, after a 54-year absence. On 19 October the Prime Minister named her Director of the newly founded Latvian Institute.

Somebody who returns from abroad a year before assuming their post, and almost certainly held a passport of a different country for most of their life, should count as a "yes"

Comment: Countries that considered themselves under foreign occupation for decades (like the Baltic ones) often have relaxed the rules of residency etc. The same goes for those that saw the overthrow of long-term dictatorial regimes. The two conditions kinda overlap for the Baltics actually.

Comment: There is a difference in someone living abroad because they want to and because their country is occupied by a  foreign power. Also it appears that she was actually born in Latvia and not born in a foreign country which is what I think the question was asking about rather then someone moving abroad.

Comment: These considerations are interesting but I don't see how they invalidate the answer.

Comment: I don't think she is considered a foreign citizen as she was born and that country and later forced to flee because it was occupied by another foreign power.

Comment: If she looks like a duck, quacks like a duck and swims like a duck... Having local citizenship is the easy part. The hard part is not having a foreign one.

Comment: And what most countries care about is having local citizenship and having been born with it. Having citizenship in another country is generally only an issue when they don't recognize it in the first place. In the US having dual citizenship wouldn't prevent you from being president.

Comment: Is there any statistics regarding that? Local citizenship is a weak signal since it's not hard to acquire. Not having another one is much stronger since it's harder to fake.

Comment: What do you mean it is not hard to acquire? It is kind of hard to change where you are born (or influence that at all) after the fact. The example you gave is someone who was born in a country, later left the country because it was occupied, and finally came back when it was freed.

Comment: Very few countries differentiate between people who were born there and then acquired other citizenship, and people who were naturalized.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that in the example you used she was a citizen from birth and there is no evidence that she ever gave it up when she was abroad. In fact she gave up her other citizenship when she assumed office.

Comment: Citizenship from birth usually incurs no additional rights or abilities. It does not turn you into a spiderman unless we're talking about the US.

Comment: @JoeW the place of birth is irrelevant.  The question is whether a foreigner can become prime minister or president.  A naturalized citizen is not a foreigner.  Whether she was naturalized or obtained her citizenship through other means, Vaira Vīķe-Freiberga is not an example of the phenomenon in question.  If it were, there would be probably dozens of examples, because politicians retuning from exile to assume a presidency or prime ministry is a fairly common phenomenon.

Comment: @phoog And I am saying that she was born in the country which makes her a citizen and not a foreigner meaning this doesn't address the question. It is a red herring to claim that she is a foreigner because she was forced to flee the country due to Soviet occupation. In this case she isn't a naturalized citizen as she has been one her entire life.

Comment: @JoeW where someone is born has an impact on their citizenship only inasmuch as nationality law takes it into account. 
In fact, according to Wikipedia, pre-soviet nationality law in Latvia was based on jus sanguinis, so the place of her birth is indeed irrelevant.  What matters is that her parents were Latvian.

Comment: @phoog And she never gave up her citizenship when she fled the country meaning she was never a foreigner at any point in time. Just because someone moves to another country doesn't mean they become a foreigner in their home country.

Comment: @alamar AKAIK, the US does not distinguish between birthright citizens and citizens who were not citizens at birth unless you are running for president. Which is not really something 99.99% of birthright citizens will achieve or even seek out in the first place